# How load the wrong microcode on the CPU?

Tags: amd-processor, amd-ryzen, microcode

One friend of mine bought a Ryzen 3 3200G. Seems like it is same as 3400G without SMT. Seems to be disabled in the microcode.

So I was wondering whether it is at all possible to load the microcode of 3400G into 3200G to see what happens.

Questions:

1. How to identify microcode for 3400G?
2. How to force load it into the existing 3200G?
3. How to enable SMT on the fly after this is done?

Even if this is done, I doubt SMT will be enabled on the fly but still it will be something interesting to try.

P.S. I found some info about modifying microcode but no info how to exactly load modified microcode in linux.
https://linustechtips.com/topic/1120683-modifying-the-cpu-microcode-is-it-possible/

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema, the same way as any other question. How do you do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with Ubuntu, you might delete this question and repost it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @heynnema, I see that nobody knows here, so I don't care much. On the other hand there are a lot of questions that are about bash, ansible and whatnot which are related to Ubuntu as much as this question is. Basically people want to or are using Ubuntu. Whether answer applies to other distros I don't know. Bootstrapping often is distro specific. I can't understand your concern. But I'm repeating yourself. I see no explanation in your two comments.

Comment: Sigh. This is a hardware question, and asking how to load incorrect firmware. This is a **Ubuntu** support site. Your question has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: This question seems OK here to me, but if it were off-topic due to being about hardware, it would also be off topic on [unix.se] and should be posted on [SU]. Unfortunately I don't know where you're most likely to find the requisite expertise. The comments at the link you posted aren't encouraging!